# Laravel 5.4 Browser testing, cannot type into input fields: X display is required

Tags: laravel, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-5.4, laravel-dusk

I am following the Laravel Documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk) to create browser tests for my application.

After some trials, I got Dusk to run. It runs only when `--headless` mode is used -- otherwise, PHP unit hangs without any output.

Anyway, I got the following error message when trying to test the login page:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException: unknown error: 
an X display is required for keycode conversions, consider using Xvfb
```

The code is nothing special, just typing in the fields:

```php
    $this->browse(function ($browser) use ($user) {

        $browser->visit('/login')
                ->type('email', $user->email)
                ->type('password', 'secret')
                ->press('Login')
                ->assertPathIs('/home');
    });
```

I am new to testing and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this simple but deadly problem and finally get Dusk working. Hope this will help other newcomers to the world of feature testing with Dusk:

> Make sure you run `php artisan dusk` in your **host environment**, *not* in the Laravel Homestead virtual machine.

Before doing that, you might want to make sure:

1. `DB_HOST`in your `.env` file is set to `192.168.10.10` or whatever you set in your host file that points to your Laravel app in your local development environment.
2. You don't use extra options for the remoteWebServer, i.e., simply using the default `'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()` is enough to get you started.